# Python Selenium get text out of a class

Tags: python, selenium, class, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Hey I want to have the text which is in this class and print it in the console.
How can I do this?
I have tried:

```
profileName = driver.find_element_by_class_name("._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl").text()
print(profileName)
```

I would be very happy if you could help me.
Tom Rudolph

Comment: Try this method once `driver.find_element_by_class_name("._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl").get_attribute("innerText")`

Comment: @pmadhu really?

Comment: @Prophet - Why not, anything wrong.

Comment: @pmadhu `find_element_by_class_name` accepting singe class name only

Comment: @Prophet - Oh okay, I dint see it, just copy pasted it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it not `text()` in python,  it is `.text`

also this `._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl` looks dynamic and a `css_selector` not `class_name`.

**Code 1 :**

```
profileName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl").text
print(profileName)
```

**Code 2 :**

```
profileName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl").get_attribute('innerHTML')
print(profileName)
```

Answer (score 0):

In case that element has all these class names you just have to change from `find_element_by_class_name` to `find_element_by_css_selector`, as following:

```
profileName = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl").text()
print(profileName)
```

However I'm quite sure these class names are dynamically changing so this will not work.
Also, make sure you added some delay / wait before accessing the element.

Answer (score 0):

maybe try this
is from the BeautifulSoup library

from the beginning:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = 'my_site'
r = request.get (url)
re1 = BeautifulSoup (r.text, "lxml")
re2 = re1.body.find_all ('div', {'class': '._7UhW9.fKFbl.yUEEX.KV-D4.fDxYl'})
for syntax in re2 [:]:
     print (syntax)
```

where there is div you can put another tag where this class is (a, p, h)
where there is div you can put another tag where this class is (a, p, h)

and in selenium, instead of 'element' use 'elements', when harvesting it is better to collect everything: D
But when you want to click an element or type something (send_keys () or click ()) you have to use a single number of characters, which is 'element' and not 'elements'

I do this for seleneium webdriver

```
data1 = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('class')
data2 = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('css_selector")

if len(data1) >  0:
  do something
if len(data2) > 0:
 do something
```

you can always add an else if you want to see how the error pops up, print (len (data1)) or data2 to see how much data you have collected etc.